# Install Self Signed Certificate to Alpine Linux

Tags: linux, ssl

How do you install a self signed cert chain into Alpine Linux?

I've a self signed cert **chain** that I've been using in Ubuntu, for example:

bacon.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
328FjQIFJNVBLAHBLAH
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
7CJAMIDDLEBLAH80A
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
328FjOTHERVBLAHBLAH
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

And in Ubuntu, I run the following commands to install this **cert chain**:

```
cp /tmp/certs/bacon.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/bacon.crt
update-ca-certificates
```

Easy!

---

However, on Alpine Linux:

```
# cp /tmp/certs/bacon.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/bacon.crt
/usr/local/share/ca-certificates # update-ca-certificates
WARNING: ca-cert-bacon.crt.pem does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping
```

And if I try to break my certs into 3 chunks to spoon-feed this distro:

/tmp/certs/1.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
328FjQIFJNVBLAHBLAH
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

/tmp/certs/2.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
328FjOTHERVBLAHBLAH
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

/tmp/certs/3.crt

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
328FjQIFJNVBLAHBLAH
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Now it doesn't throw an error during *cert installation* but still can't authenticate against other self-signed endpoints.

Comment: Shouldn't you configure it in `nginx` also?

Comment: @chicks - I do not leverage nginx anywhere in this setup.

Comment: Then how are you trying to authenticate with these certs?  Via `ssh`?

Comment: @chicks - I'm attempting to upload a docker image from this Alpine Linux image to an internal Docker Registry. The docker daemon leverages the machine's certs to execute the docker login. Again, this is working fine on all my other Linux machines (Ubuntu, CentOS, RHEL, Debian) as *those* Linux variations are able to swallow a whole cert chain in one gulp, where this one complains.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with Docker to be able to address that part of it, but I added the `docker-registry` tag so hopefully someone will find it that is more aware.

Comment: You can flag the question and ask the moderators move it so you don't have to delete it on one site and create it on another site. It also resets the question's score. For whatever reasons, the Stack Exchange network does not allow you to migrate it yourself. Also see [Author initiated migration to other SE sites?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254851)

Comment: @chicks - the reason I left out I was interacting with a docker registry, is because all the other unix-based commands are broken inside this container too. `wget`, `curl` and `docker login` all fail with the same `x509 cert` errors. Which is why I don't want to zoom in on that part of the problem.

Comment: Pasting the output of those commands could be helpful.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Figured it out. Gosh.

`/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is actually appending each individual cert from `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates`.

1. Get a clean environment (This was my first major issue)
2. Break your certs chain into a separate parts for each BEGIN/END pair you have.

   1. company-Root.crt
   2. company-X.crt
   3. company-Y.crt
   4. company-Z.crt
   5. company-Issuing.crt
3. If you're being *extra* careful, load one at a time, starting with the `company-Root.crt` cert, then run `update-ca-certificates`.
4. Repeat until all certs have been processed.
5. Verify that `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` contains the updates at the bottom of the file.

Comment: command from 3. always gives me `WARNING: ca-certificates.crt does not contain exactly one certificate or CRL: skipping` though my crt file contains only one bunch of begin-end

Comment: ok, i've found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/54100906/1713660