# Listing installed certificates in alpine

Tags: security, ssl, certificates, alpine-linux

I know there are several [topics](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/464484/install-self-signed-certificate-to-alpine-linux) regarding installation of certiciates in `alpine`.

Is there a way however to list the already trusted root CA's in `alpine`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` is a long text file of concatenated certificates, each in PEM format.  To view details of each one, you need something like:

```
openssl crl2pkcs7 -nocrl -certfile /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt | openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -noout
```

This creates a temporary PKCS#7 file of all the certificates in the file, then prints their subject and issuer fields only.  If you want all the details, add `-text` to the 2nd command.